# Null Getting into the array

Tags: java, multithreading

I am wondering how a null gets into this array of memcached objects.

```
Object[] value = (Object[]) SuperCache.getInstance()
                    .get(key);
Object data = cacheStore.getValue();
Object[] newValue;
    if (data != null) {
        if (value == null || value.length <= 0) {
            newValue = new Object[1];
            newValue[0] = data;
            log.info("CacheThread : no value found for k"
                    + key + ", adding a new value now v"
                    + data);
        } else {
            newValue = new Object[value.length + 1];
            newValue[0] = data;
            System.arraycopy(value, 0, newValue, 1,
                    value.length);
            for (int i = 0; i < newValue.length; i++) {
----->          if (newValue[i] == null)
                    log.error("null getting into cache here, for key "
                            + key);
            }
        }
        cacheData(key, newValue, cacheStore.getExpiry());
        log.info("CacheThread " + this.toString()
            + " Lenght of Array" + newValue.length
            + "for k" + key + "v" + newValue);
    }
```

At the line pointed to above, I am checking if the newValue array has a null. But since you notice that I am building the array via iterations.

Why am I getting a null here ?

Comment: You're copying an array of length `value.length` into an array of length `value.length+1`. Shouldn't you expect 1 item to remain null ?(first item in your case cause you're starting to copy from `destPos = 1`). See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)

Comment: I have debuged it and not found the issue. Hence the question here. Why the downvote ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array `value` can contain `null` values. You are not checking against them anywhere.

Just print them in the second line to verify this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
      if (value[i] == null)
            log.error("null getting into cache here, at index" + i);
```

Comment: Good hint, existing data has null

Comment: To your service :) pls consider approving

Answer (score 0):

```
else {
            newValue = new Object[value.length + 1];
            newValue[0] = data; // this part is assigning only index 0 to an object, you're looping to < newValue.length index
            System.arraycopy(value, 0, newValue, 1,
                    value.length);
            for (int i = 0; i < newValue.length; i++) {
                if (newValue[i] == null) // when i = 1 onwards, it will be null as they are not assigned yet
                    log.error("null getting into cache here, for key "
                            + key);
            }
        }
```

Seems to be the problem lies on newValue[0] = data;

Only the index 0 will be assign to the `data` variable object. However your loop is looping to the size of `newValue` array. Therefore index 1 onwards will be NULL.

```
else {
            newValue = new Object[value.length + 1];
            System.arraycopy(value, 0, newValue, 1,
                    value.length);
            for (int i = 0; i < newValue.length; i++) {
               newValue[i] = data;
               if (newValue[i] == null)
                    log.error("null getting into cache here, for key "
                            + key);
            }
```

This is probably what you need.

Comment: If I make your change, all data elements will be replaced by new `data` and I will loose existing data.